# The sound does not work on the analog output

Tags: drivers, sound, amd-graphics

I am new to Linux
The sound does not work on the analog output of regular headphones. I tried more than one distribution and it does not work
It only works on Linux Mint distribution

```
Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
```

Comment: Not enough info. What kind of computer? What kind of sound chip? What kind of headphones/speakers/whatever? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice; switching stack being one possible solution (as changing kernel also changes kernel modules (commonly called *drivers*)), but how are we to know what options you have available until you tell us what Ubuntu product, what release of that Ubuntu product?